# Return the id for a created rails item with json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xcode, json

In XCode (iOS) I am accessing a rails database using JSON. I have created specific actions to retrieve data from the database and to enter data into the database.

I want to insert a record in my database and immediately return the id for the created object. But I cannot find a way to 'link' these actions together.

For inserting data, I use a request like this:

```
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://..."]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:"@POST"];
    [request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
    NSData *objectData = [NSData alloc];
    NSError *parseError = nil;
    objectData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:myData options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&parseError];
    [request setHTTPBody:objectData];
```

For data retrieval I use the following:

```
    NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSData *myContent = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://..."]];
    NSError *parseError = nil;
    NSInputStream *myStream = nil;

    myStream = [[NSInputStream alloc] initWithData:myContent];
    [myStream open];

   myArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithStream:myStream options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&parseError];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in the controller json action you can use something like

```
def json 
  #-- do your magic to fill @object --
  if @object.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render :json => {:id => @object.id} } # Return the id
      # format.json { render :json => @object } #You can return the whole object
      format.html { render :string => "#{@object.inspect}" }
    end
  else
    render :json => {:error => "OMG Failed to save the model!"} 
  end
end
```